# Channel mapping with NAudio

Tags: windows, audio, naudio

I'm using NAudio to play some generated PCM audio. Unfortunately, the target device(DualSense) only shows itself as a 2-channel device, instead of being available as a 4-channel device(R, L, RR, RL).
I tried playing with Multiplexing and channel mapping in NAudio, but it always errors out when trying to select more than 2 channels.

I know, that EqualizerAPO is able to somehow do the channel copy for each device, and it is working with channel copying, but I want to control it from the code.

Is there some way to either tell NAudio, that this device is 4 channels and ignore all the errors or some other workaround for that?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Instead of using WaveOut, you can use WasapiOut / ASIO, it gives way more control over channels.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).